# URL scheme or intent for the Google Street View App (Not Google Maps)

Tags: android, google-street-view

13

I'm using Google Cardboard with the Street View App. I want to be able to create a link that sends users directly into the Street View App to view a specific location.(NOT google maps street view)

There was a similar question asked 2.5 years ago with no response.(below) 
[URL scheme for the Google Street View App (Not Google Maps)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601729/url-scheme-for-the-google-street-view-app-not-google-maps)
If there has not been any feature evolution since,and no way to provide intent or URL scheme into GSV App, I will have to recreate a similar experience in the Streetview API. 
I would need to be able to launch the cardboard view from Street view maps, and provide the smooth Panorama navigational transition provided in GSV App Cardboard implementations.Does anyone know a solution?